# why is datepicker not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

following http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_datepicker.ashx
Using Asp.Net MVC can someone please help me as to why my datepicker is not working.
Nothing happens when I click the text box.
Where the datepicker should appear?

```
    <input type="text" id="simple-date" />  

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // the jQuery ready shortcut  
    $(function () {  
        // set up our datepicker  
        $("#simple-date").datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` included into your page?

Comment: Are you getting any output errors in chrome/firefox dev console?

Comment: how do I know what JQuery JQuery UI link to paste into the top of my page. It doesnt tell me in that URL.

Comment: Yes it does. There is a link [How Do I Start Using jQuery?](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_introduction.ashx).

Comment: I dont see there what to include in my cshtml page. I tried Script.Require("jQuery"); but no joy

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery, jQueryUI links are added than try change script as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#simple-date").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```